# appendTo div between li

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have the following code

```
<div id="element1" style="display:none"></div>

<ul>
    <li id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="item2">Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

On click I want to move element1 after item1

```
<ul>
    <li id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <div id="element1" style="display:none"></div>
    <li id="item2">Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

If I use

```
$('#element1').appendTo('#item1');
```

The element append inside li

```
<li id="item1">Item 1 <div id="element1">...</div></li>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) for this:

```
$('#element1').insertAfter('#item1');
```

*But* a `<div>` in a `<ul>` isn't valid HTML, you need to insert only a `<li>` element here, so I'd wrap it first:

```
$('#element1').wrap('<li />').parent().insertAfter('#item1');
```